# Predict delay before next retry on a rate-limited API

Tags: machine-learning, prediction, rate-limiting

I'm using an API that rate-limits me, forcing me to wait and retry my request if I hit a URL too frequently. Let's say for the sake of argument that I don't know what the specific rate limit threshold is (and don't want to hardcode one into my app even if I did know).

I can make an API call and either watch it succeed, or get back a response saying I've been rate limited, then try again shortly, and I can record the total time elapsed for all tries before I was able to successfully complete an API call.

What algorithms would be a good fit for predicting the minimum time I need to wait before retrying an API call after hitting the rate limit?

Comment: Why exactly do you need machine learning to find a threshold? Just count how many times you hit the URL within a given timeframe.

Answer (score 0):

Use something like a one sided binary search.

See [page 134 of The Algorithm Design Manual](http://books.google.com/books?id=7XUSn0IKQEgC&pg=PA134&lpg=PA134&dq=one+sided+binary+search&source=bl&ots=z7cCSUGT_d&sig=hhl0qrR3-IweEs9iJ2YWFiDoXEg&hl=en&sa=X&ei=pqy1UcfVBNKargHu9IGYCw&sqi=2&ved=0CFAQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=one%20sided%20binary%20search&f=false):

> Now suppose we have an array *A* consisting of a run of 0's, followed by
>   an unbounded run of 1's, and would like to identify the exact point of
>   transition between them. Binary search on the array would provide the
>   transition point in **⌈lg n ⌉** tests, if we had a bound *n* on the
>   number of elements in the array. In the absence of such a bound, we can
>   test repeatedly at larger intervals (A[1], A[2], A[4], A[8], A[16], ...)
>   until we find a first non-zero value. Now we have a window containing
>   the target and can proceed with binary search. This *one-sided binary
>   search* finds the transition point *p* using at most **2 ⌈lg(p)⌉**
>   comparisons, regardless of how large the array actally is. One-sided
>   binary search is most useful whenever we are looking for a key that
>   probably lies close to our current position.